# Regex pattern for first name without whitespace or numbers

Tags: regex

I have this regex pattern

/^[^-\s][^0-9][a-zA-Z\s-]+$/

I am a bit confused on why when I test it on https://www.regextester.com/ 
My pattern allows one single number to be added before the string. Meaning that if I type in '2Mantas' it will still accept it whereas '22Mantas' will fail the test. I do not want any numbers or whitespace to be allowed. Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Please provide some sample inputs that should pass, and some that should fail.

Comment: any string passes if you include one number before it '5steve' '2daniel' etc. but '22steve' would fail.

Comment: Yes, you've indicated that above. Can you provide some inputs that *should* and *should not* pass? For example, we can assume that `5steve` and `2daniel` should **not** pass, but can you give us an example for what *should* pass?

Answer (score 0):

The first two rules in your current regular expression break down to the following:

1. `^[^\s-]` - the first character in the string should not be a whitespace or a hyphen. This explains why `2steve` is accepted - `2` is not a whitespace or a hyphen character.
2. `[^0-9]` - the second character in the strnig should not be a digit. This iexplains why `22steve` is not accepted - the `2` in the second position is a digit, which violates this rule.

Assuming you don't want anything but capital and lowercase letters in your first name input, *and* the name shouldn't start with a whitespace or hyphen character, you can simplify to a subset of your current regular expression:

```
/^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z-\s]+$/
```

[<sup>Regex101</sup>](https://regex101.com/r/l4NaHT/1)

Comment: if you add a single digit before the name it still passes on https://www.regextester.com

Comment: @MantasStanionis - yes, you're correct, my mistake, I've updated my regex.

Answer (score 0):

You have two negation groups so it is saying the first character cannot be whitespace and the second character cannot be a number. If you put the whitespace and digit in the first brackets it will work as desired.

```
^[^-\s\d][a-zA-Z\s-]+$
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

Get string, that starts with exactly one digit, and after this digits should be expression, that contains only strings (greedy)

```
^\d{1}([a-zA-Z]+)
```

https://regex101.com/r/wtBwd7/1